# Do heap dumps work on encrypted cloud servers?

Tags: spring-boot

This is a question to understand how Spring Boot applications work:
Assuming my cloud instance is very secure, including encrypted data in use. Is the data in a heap dump readable/unencrypted or will its content be encrypted?

This question came up during a discussion on cloud security.

Comment: My assumption: your JVM must be able to use the memory, consequently the heap dump is "normal" (unencrypted). The encryption should be transparent to your application/JVM and any process shouldn't have to care if it runs in an "encrypted" environment or not. But this should be rather trivial to try out, no? Deploy an app, create the dump, check the dump. Once you have tried that, write an answer under your question so that future visitors can look it up.

Comment: Thanks knitti. Currently we do not have access to this kind of hardware, so I had to ask beforehand.

Comment: There's a whole research area about encrypting data so that you can manipulate it without decrypting it (and without knowing the decryption key) called homomorphic encryption. Those are almost always quite specialized algorithms for very specific operations and not the kind of thing you can simply "apply to an existing Spring boot application", so it's pretty unlikely that that's what you're looking at. And if you aren't looking at that, then anything that manipulates the data needs to do so on the decrypted data by definition.

Comment: Thanks Joachim. I have heard of homomorphic encryption, but this is currently beyond our capabilities. I was thinking of HW with secure enclaves and try to get a grip on how secure the data in use really is. But if a powerful tool like a heap dump can simply read the whole data in memory I might end up looking into homomorphic encryption...